# How to make service worker register only on the first visit?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

Hi I have an ejs template on express which generates HTML. I have written my service worker registration code in this template which is common for all pages of the website and thus, the registration code ends up being there on every page of the website. So, on every user visit, the service worker registration code is run which I believe is bad. How to make this code run only on the first visit of a user?

Please find my code below:

```
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          var hashes = {};
          ["appCss", "appJs"].map((val,idx) => {
              let prop;
              if(document.getElementById(val)) {
                  prop = val.toLowerCase().indexOf("css") == -1 ? "src" : "href";
                  hashes[val] = document.getElementById(val)[prop];
              }
          });
          hashes = JSON.stringify(hashes);
          navigator.serviceWorker
              .register(`/service-worker.js?hash=${encodeURIComponent(hashes)}`)
              .then(function(registration) {
                  console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
              }, function(err) {
                  console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed:', err);
              });
      });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Should'nt you keep the service worker registration on every page load (it's the goal of a service worker) ? Let your browser handle this. However within the worker handle it's lifecycle using the provided events. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Basic_architecture

Comment: Yes, I have kept the registration code on all the pages. But once the service worker gets registered on the first visit, shouldn't we prevent it from registering itself again? What I mean by that is - console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope); runs on every subsequent visit of the website

Comment: I've answered below. Yes you should let the registration on every page of your scope. Your browser will detect once registered the SW is already installed and trigger the correct events.

Answer (score 9):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register) :

> The register() method of the ServiceWorkerContainer interface creates or updates a ServiceWorkerRegistration for the given scriptURL.
>
> If successful, a service worker registration ties the provided script URL to a scope, which is subsequently used for navigation matching. **You can call this method unconditionally from the controlled page. I.e., you don't need to first check whether there's an active registration.**

So you should always call `register` on your page. The browser API will handle this for you.